# Удалить последние изменения события

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть событие которое при клике устанавливает css свойство (неважно какому элементу, там много всего повешено на click.

```
$(document).on('click', ".flag1", function() {
            $('.flag1').css('background-image', 'url(img-url)').css('color', 'white');
        });
```

Как написать функцию которая будет при клике на другой элемент отменять эти изменения, то есть уюерет свойства css? Но важно, чтобы обработчик событий остался и можно было кликать сколько уодно раз и эти свойства css применялись бы снова.
Пробовал off (но он вроде как удалит обработчик событий), unbind и никак(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функции `addClass()` и `removeClass()`.

Вот пример:

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
 $("#txt").addClass("red");
});
$("#remove").on("click", function() {
 $("#txt").removeClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="remove">REMOVE</button>
<p id="txt">My Text</p>
```